Run application in sandbox mode
I have installed an application in /Applications/.
I want this application to be run in sandbox mode.
I can do this manually with sandbox-exec but i don't want to start this application through terminal.
Is there a way to check sandbox mode somewhere in the application parameters ?
Thanks
